# How to Save UIImage to a Transparent PNG?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, png, transparent

I'm not sure where I'm doing the mistake, that's why I'd like to paste here some block of codes in order to find out what went wrong.

I have some PNG images that have transparent background and with using the block of codes below I'm trying save the selected image to application folder and NSUserDefault. And then I'm trying to call that saved image from application folder and display on UIBarButtonItem.

*The purpose of saving to NSUserDefault as well is for testing.*

So,

**This is how I'm selecting the image.**

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgPicker.delegate = self;
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imgPicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
        imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;

        [self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}
```

**And with this I'm saving it to application using didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo;**

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage])
    {
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        //I believe this has the problem.
        NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

        NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppImages"];;

        NSError *error = nil;

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

        NSString *fileName = [stringPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logoImage.png"];
        [pngData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
        NSUserDefaults *logoUserDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [logoUserDef setValue:pngData forKey:@"logoImageData"];
    }
}
```

*Note: I don't have problem for the images that doesn't have transparent background.*

**And lastly this is how I'm calling it from both Application and NSUserDefault.**

Using both NSUserDefaults and AppDirectory to see if they're showing different result.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"logoImageData"])
{
    NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    UIImage *testing = [UIImage imageWithData:[user valueForKey:@"logoImageData"]];

    NSString * documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImage * image = [self loadImageWithFileName:@"logoImage" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:documentsDirectory];

    UIBarButtonItem *logoBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(logoTapped)];
    logoBarButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 0, 9, 90);
    logoBarButton.image = [logoBarButton.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:@[logoBarButton]];
}
```

And method that returns UIImage from App Document.

```
-(UIImage *)loadImageWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@.%@",   directoryPath, @"AppImages", fileName, [extension lowercaseString]]];

    return result;
}
```

I don't know from where I'm doing wrong but as always, when I select image that has transparent background. It always convert its background to White. I need to save it as it is as transparent. I've searched a lot but couldn't find anything to solve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hm... Seems like you specifically be extracting the data when fetching the image. I'll write up a suggestion in a sec.

Comment: Actually, the "testing" image isn't transparent? It seems as if your code there is correct... Are you sure the button's background is clear? I'd also recommend putting your image in a UIImageView for testing just to check for transparency.

Comment: @LyndseyScott thanks for your reply. I need to mention that I believe the problem occurs when I save the image after I pick, because after the saving, to make sure what I had I go and check it in my application folder. If the selected image was transparent then its background become white. If non-transparent was selected then its working fine. So as a result my problem is I'm not getting what I select.

Comment: But how can you tell by just looking at the image in the application folder that it's not transparent? The background will appear white when you look at just the file even though the image is transparent since the image has to be displayed on something and can't just be floating in space.

Comment: The original image has white logo text on transparent background. Depending the NSUserDefault I'm checking possibilities, if 'logoImageData' is not there as a value, I call original logo image and place it on UIBarButtonItem. But if the 'logoImageData' is there as a value then image that is saved in app directory is getting call. By the way I'm using the same image on both approach. But the saved image become fully white and when I place it on black UIBarButtonItem it doesn't show the white logo text. Just full white.

Comment: Here's the thing... I asked whether your `testing` image came out correctly because you're retrieving it in the right way. As for `image`, I seems as if you're not. So I ask again, are you sure `testing`'s also not transparent? Or is it just `image` that's not transparent?

Comment: Sorry for the late response @LyndseyScott . I've checked everything that you've asked me to do. The" testing" is transparent image.. I tested the saved image on UIImageView the result was same as on UIBarButtonItem. 120x44 dimension become fully white. But to make sure I also tested the original image on UIImageView and its working fine. By the way before I start testing I set UIImageView background to black to see white logo text and I only seen it on my original image. I really don't know what else I should do to solve this problem. It's obvious that the problem occurs on saving now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, but I'll write up a suggestion.

Comment: Actually one last question... How are you so certain that you're in fact fetching an image if it's white on white? How do you know for sure that the image isn't just blank? Have you tested your code with non-white pngs?

Comment: Is there any way that I can have your e-mail and send you the images that I'm working with. For also about your question, yes I've tried it and the results were same.

Comment: I'd like to thank you @LyndseyScott, without your directions I wouldn't find where the problem was. Thank you again. /bow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem!

The block of codes that I posted with my question have nothing wrong. The problem was occurring from iTunes, when I synchronize images from my Mac to my iPhone iTunes convert them to JPEG and because of this images loses their transparency etc... and when I select images using my app, I was selecting them as JPEG without being aware and that's why I had these problems.

So I came up with a solution to have images via email. I just send them from my mac to iPhone with e-mail, and by this images didn't lose anything as a feature. After that when I used them in app as a right image, the program worked as it supposed to be.

Comment: We may also test the PNG files in Simulator. We can drag and drop png images from 'Finder' directly to 'Photos' app in Simulator. These images are returned as proper png images with transparency, from imagepicker in our app.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
     [logoUserDef setValue:pngData forKey:@"logoImageData"];
```

but I don't see where you synchronize. So add:

```
      [logoUserDef synchronize];
```

Comment: I'll add this to see the changes. I'll inform you the result. Thanks

Comment: I've tested out. Adding `[logoUserDef synchronize];` didn't make any difference. The code still converting transparent background to white.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to preserve the transparency when saving an image to the Documents directory after using

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage *img = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [yourButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    //do something with pngData
}
```

The key is the **UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage** instead of other options like UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage.